# JavaFX dynamic column setting

Tags: java, dynamic, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I have problem with adding of column to TableView dynamically. The problem is, that it adds data for one cell into entire row. I think the problem could be in my callback, or in the part where I add data in tableView.
This is my callback method:

```
Callback<CellDataFeatures<String,String> ,ObservableValue<String>> cb;
cb = new Callback<CellDataFeatures<String,String> ,ObservableValue<String>>() { 
   @Override
   public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<String, String> param) {
     return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue());
   } 
 };
```

and this is where I add data, listOfNewValues is ArrayList which contains new String values:

```
ObservableList<String> addData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
addData = aktualTable.getItems();
for(String data : listOfNewValues) {
  addData.add(data); 
}
aktualTable.setItems(addData);
```

Comment: I think you are missing something fundamental about how `TableView` works (but sorry if I am wrong about this). When you do `TableView.setItems(someList)`, *each item* in the list represents an *entire row* in the table. So your second block of code doesn't "add data", it replaces all the data. You have represented each row by a single `String`, and it looks like each column has the same data value.

Comment: To tell the truth, you were right halfway, I knew how does .setItem work, but after I read your comment It somehow hit me with what was the issue there. Thanks